# Locking during Insert into Partitioned table postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-locking

Is constraint exclusion possible during inserts?

```
create table parent(id int)

    create table c1 ( constraint  c1_constarint CHECK (id = 1)) inherits parent
    create table c2 ( constraint  c2_constarint CHECK (id = 2)) inherits parent
    create table c3 ( constraint  c3_constarint CHECK (id = 3)) inherits parent
```

when doing 
insert into c1 values(1) it is acquiring RowExclusive locks on all children(c2, c3)

Is there a way can we do constraint exclusion during insert? Or any hints available to perform this action

Comment: Why is the `ROW EXCLUSIVE LOCK` a problem?

Comment: I'm running 2 sessions concurrently, 1st sessions: Truncate c1; Insert into c1;- Truncate is creating AccessExclusive and insert checking all Childs with RowExclusive Lock. 2nd Session: Truncate c2; Insert into c2; - Truncate is creating AccessExclusive on c2 and Insert is trying to create RowExclusive on all Childs. In this scenario Session 2 c1 and Session 1 c2 RowExclusive locks are colliding. This is creating deadlock.

Comment: I just tried on v10, and inserting into `c1` only locks `c1`. Can you come up with a reproducible test case?

Comment: The version in which I'm running is 8.2, maybe its corrected going forward?

Comment: 8.2?? You tagged 9.3. 8.2 has been dead for ~7 years.